# laravel показать только на первой странице

Tags: php, laravel

сделал слайдер на главном при перелистывание страницы оно не должно отображаться , site/public/ это главная , при перелистывание добавляется  ?page=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если мне правильно удалось понять суть, то можно так:

```
if (request('page', 1) == 1) {
    // сработает только для первой страницы
}
```